# Error with schema update

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I use FOSBundle to get in relation with attribute handledBy and createdBy and run command update schema I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ4WP.png)

```
//Entity

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User ") */
        private $handledBy;

        /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User ") */
        private $createdBy;
//FOSuser
 /**
     * @ORM\column(name="handledBy")
    **/
    private $handledBy;
```

Could you please help me  fix this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra whitespace in your target entity definition.